# Docker cannot start container no such file or directory

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, boot2docker

I'm unable to start my container after build and I got :

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container ogc-mysql: no such file or directory
Error: failed to start one or more containers
```

Here is my Docker file :

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER Davin Kevin

# Install latest updates
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

# Install mysql client and server
RUN apt-get -y install mysql-client mysql-server curl

# Enable remote access (default is localhost only, we change this
# otherwise our database would not be reachable from outside the container)
RUN sed -i -e"s/^bind-address\s*=\s*127.0.0.1/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf

# Install database
ADD ./database.sql /var/db/database.sql

# Set Standard settings
ENV user ogc
ENV password ogc
ENV url file:/var/db/database.sql
ENV right READ

# Install starting script
ADD ./start-database.sh /usr/local/bin/start-database.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-database.sh

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/start-database.sh"]
```

And my sh script only does :

```
docker build -t ogc-mysql .
docker run --name ogc-mysql -d -p 3306:3306 ogc-mysql
```

And reffering to the Docker documentation :

> docker build will return a no such file or directory error if the file
>   or directory does not exist in the uploaded context. This may happen
>   if there is no context, or if you specify a file that is elsewhere on
>   the Host system. The context is limited to the current directory (and
>   its children) for security reasons, and to ensure repeatable builds on
>   remote Docker hosts. This is also the reason why ADD ../file will not
>   work.

This command : `docker ps -a` returns :

```
CONTAINER ID : 70..
IMAGE : ogc-sql:latest
COMMAND : "/usr/local/bin/star"
CREATED : 13 seconds ago
STATUS : /
PORTS : /
NAMES : ogc-mysql
```

The fact is that this command works successfully on Mac OS..

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Problem solved, it was a line-ending problem in the sh files...

Comment: It might be helpful if you clarified what the line-ending problem was.

Comment: true.. that would be helpful

Answer (score 8):

I got this when integrating and invoking a shell script using `CMD` which had Windows line breaks (CR+LF) in my container.

After converting to Linux line endings (LF only) and rebuilding the container, it would start just fine.

Answer (score -1):

The docker run syntax is
from https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run

docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

as ogc-mysql is not an image or a command, this fails

can you post the result of

```
docker ps -a
```